# Regular expression that captures optional parenthesis

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string like:

> Linux (pronounced /ˈlɪnəks/ LIN-əks or, less frequently, /ˈlaɪnəks/ LYN-əks) is a Unix-like computer operating system assembled under the model of free and open-source software development and distribution.

I want to write a regular expression in python that captures sentences like above which contains a keyword (`Linux` in this case) followed by optional parenthesis followed by a mandatory "is" or "are".

Comment: Something like this? `(Linux|otherkeyword)\s*(?:\(.*\))?\s*(?:is|are).*` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5zonW3/2

Comment: It wont match other patterns. Check this: https://regex101.com/r/5zonW3/5

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the answer @MohammadYusufGhazi

Comment: Use this `(Linux|otherkeyword)\s*(?:\(.*?\))?\s*(?:is|are).*` if there are more parenthesis after `is,are`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming some things.

1. There is always a space between the keyword and the optional open paranthesis.
2. There is always a space after the close paranthesis.
3. There must be at least one character between the spaces.
4. Sentences consist of (before the end) any character except a period.
5. Sentences always end with a period.

Try this:

```
Linux (\([^\.\(\)]*\))? (is|are)[^\.\(\)]*\.
```

Hi
It says:

- `Linux` - match exactly the word Linux followed by a space.
- `(\([^\.\(\)]*\))?` - Zero or exactly 1 times exactly match a ( followed by zero or more characters which are not .( or ) followed by exactly a )
- `(is|are)` - match a space followed by the word is or are.
- `[^\.\(\)]*\.` - match zero or more characters which are not .( or ) followed exactly by a `.`